# Backup google hosted mailboxes

Tags: g-suite, open-source

We have deployed out official mailboxes in google apps not premier edition. Does anybody know how to backup those mailboxes using any opensource tools OR is there any tool to backup mailboxes..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Look for IMAP backup tools or scripts, there are plenty of them.
You can simply enable IMAP protocol and download your messages using an IMAP backup tool.

Answer (score 0):

I find [imapfilter](http://imapfilter.hellug.gr/) a handy tool to operate IMAP enabled mail services. It is operated by a lua script where you can move/copy between IMAP folders, IMAP accounts, etc. with a simple syntax.

I've used it for archiving and moving between accounts, but I guess it would be easy to make a script to periodically copy messages from last backup date to another account.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pay service called [Backupify.com](http://www.backupify.com/). They will backup more than just Gmail. I think the cost is pretty reasonable for what they do and it's cheaper than paying for a Premier edition.